# A particle is projected in an upwards direction in a medium with resistance $\frac{g}{V}$.

Tags: classical-mechanics

A particle is projected upwards in a medium whose resistance is $\frac{gv}{V}$, where $v$ is the velocity. If $V$ is large compared to $U$, which is the velocity of projection, show that the fraction of the value of the vertical height $h$ reached by the particle is described as $$\frac{2U}{3V}$$ and the fraction of the value of the ascent time is $$\frac{U}{2V}$$ when the resistance is equal to $0$.

What does $V$ represent in this problem?

Comment: probably terminal veocity

Comment: This is probably a typo: The title says resistance $\frac{g}{V}$ but the question states $\frac{gv}{V}$.

Comment: No mention is made of the force of gravity in this problem, but I suspect from the notion of direction ("upward") and the letter $g$ (constant of gravitational acceleration?), that the particle's motion is affected by gravity as well as "resistance" (friction).

Comment: Yes, another part of the question asks for the fraction of the value of the time of descent, which is $\frac{U}{6V}$, which will be affected by $g$. Also, the resistance can also be written as $kv$, where $k=\frac{g}{V}$, (the title should say resistance of $\frac{gv}{V}$). But the question expects fractions that are dimensionless, if we take $V$ as the terminal velocity, which the particle may reach when projected upwards. The fraction $\frac{2U}{3V}$, is a fraction of the value of the height and $\frac{U}{2V}$ is a fraction of the value of the time of ascent.

Comment: Can anyone derive the above results from the projectile equation for projecting a particle vertically upwards or would you set up and solve a differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

The model can be formulated as
$$m\ddot{x}=-\frac{g}{V}\dot{x}-mg$$
The solution is 
$$x(t)=\frac{(U+mV)mV}{g}(1-e^{-\frac{g}{mV}t})-mVt$$
The maximum displacement or height corresponds to $\dot{x}(t)=0$, so we get
$$e^{-\frac{g}{mV}t_0}=\frac{mV}{U+mV}$$
where $t_0$ is the time required to reach the Max. height.
Hence, the maximum height is
$$h_{max}=\frac{mVU}{g}+\frac{(mV)^2}{g}ln\frac{mV}{U+mV}$$
The first term of $h_{max}$ should have a dimension of $meter$, so 
$$\frac{Kg.[V].m/s}{m/s^2}=m$$
finally, $[V]=m/s/Kg=[\frac{v}{m}]$, clearly, $V$ is the velocity per unit mass.

Given some values, the time $t_0$ and height $h_{max}$ can be calculated.

$$m=0.1Kg,\quad g=9.8m/s^2,\quad U=10m/s,\quad V=10m/s/Kg$$
$$t_0=0.245s,\quad h_{max}=0.776m$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks, the fractional amounts given in the original question must be approximations. This approach is more rigorous and is backed up by the plot and the substitution of hypothetical values, for $U$ and $V$, into the equations.